# typeahead does not call select when clicking on a match

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

It seems typeahead is not working when you click on a match with the mouse. I am using angular 1.3.5 and the latest ui-bootstrap build. I modified the code in the typeahead directive dismissClickHandler to check if the activeIdx is not the default and then call select to make my code work again. I wonder if I am missing something or there is a bug

here is the 'fix'

```
// Keep reference to click handler to unbind it.
  var dismissClickHandler = function (evt) {

    if (element[0] !== evt.target) {
      //is this a bug fix????
      if(scope.activeIdx != -1) scope.select(scope.activeIdx);


      resetMatches();
      scope.$digest();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Going to need more info. Please show how you are using the typeahead. And when you say it doesn't work, do you mean that it is not being dismissed or that it doesn't choose the item you clicked on? Or both? A plnkr would be helpful.

Comment: @Scott thanks for responding. It took a while to figure out, but the problem was the Angular Batarang extension on chrome! If anyone is having wacky behavior in angular, make sure  you still dont have this extension installed!

Comment: WOW Thomas, thanks a lot. I spent hours trying out to debug this.
Batarang is terrible. For other people who want's to see angular scope I suggesting  ng-inspector chrome component. 

Thanks again!